# wagmi - Error handling for writeContract action using Vanilla JS?

Tags: wagmi

I am using `wagmi` to interact with my contract ABI using Vanilla JS and having a hard time finding documentation specifically for Vanilla. I've got everything working, but have been unable to figure out how to handle errors. I am using `prepareWriteContract` and `writeContract` to set up a mint function for my NFT and everything's gravy if the transaction is successful, but I want to be able to handle errors as well (ie the user rejects the transaction, doesn't have enough funds, etc.)

```
import {
    EthereumClient,
    w3mConnectors,
    w3mProvider,
    WagmiCore,
    WagmiCoreChains,
    WagmiCoreConnectors,
} from 'https://unpkg.com/@web3modal/ethereum@2.6.2';

import { Web3Modal } from 'https://unpkg.com/@web3modal/html@2.6.2';

const { mainnet } = WagmiCoreChains;
const { configureChains, createConfig, switchNetwork, prepareWriteContract, writeContract } = WagmiCore;

async function mint() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
        const finney = 1000000000000000;
        let qty = document.getElementById('mint-quantity').value;
        
        await window.ethereum.enable();

        const txConfig = await prepareWriteContract({
            address: CONTRACT,
            abi: ABI,
            chainId: window.chainId,
            functionName: 'mint',
            args: [
                qty
            ],
            value: finney * qty
        });

        const { hash } = await writeContract(txConfig);

        console.log(hash);
    }
}
```

When the mint is successful, the `hash` constant returns the tx hash as expected, just not sure how I can handle various errors that might arise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can utilize try-catch blocks and conditionally check for specific error cases.

```
async function mint() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
        const finney = 1000000000000000;
        let qty = document.getElementById('mint-quantity').value;
        
        try {
            await window.ethereum.enable();

            const txConfig = await prepareWriteContract({
                address: CONTRACT,
                abi: ABI,
                chainId: window.chainId,
                functionName: 'mint',
                args: [qty],
                value: finney * qty
            });

            const { hash } = await writeContract(txConfig);

            console.log(hash);
            // Transaction successful, you can update your UI or perform any post-transaction logic here.
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            // Handle specific errors or display user-friendly error messages.
            if (error.message.includes("User denied transaction")) {
                // User rejected the transaction
                console.error("User denied the transaction.");
                // You can display a message to the user here.
            } else if (error.message.includes("insufficient funds")) {
                // Insufficient funds to complete the transaction
                console.error("Insufficient funds to complete the transaction.");
                // You can inform the user to add more funds to their wallet.
            } else {
                
                console.error("An error occurred while processing the transaction:", error.message);
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you for the lengthy code sample!